# best way to break out of <STDIN>

Tags: perl, loops, stdin

I'm trying to break out of stdin on a flag of some sort but when I run my code I still have to use control d to break out.  Could someone please gimme a pointer here thanks:

```
while(my $line = <STDIN>){
chomp $line;
last if $line == 0;
push @stdin, $line;
}
```

Comment: Do you type 0? Is this under Windows or Unix?

Comment: Works fine for me on Windows with v5.14.2.

Comment: Final note on this. Change your script to `last if $line == 1` and see what happens. I think the "magic" of 0 in perl is biting you here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED (twice)**

I'd go with using a string compare of one type or another. `==` is a numeric compare and forces both sides of the comparison to numeric. Almost any string other than a pure number winds up being equal to 0.

```
while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
   chomp $line;

   # use the string comparison operator...
   last if $line eq "0";
   # or use a match operator...
   # last if $line =~ m/^0$/;
   # or match on some special number
   # last if $line == 3.1415926;

   push @stdin, $line;
}
```

I tested this in windows:

`perl -e "while(my $line = <STDIN>){chomp $line;last if $line =~ m'^[.]$'}END{print @l}"`

and unix:

`perl -e 'while(my $line = <STDIN>){chomp $line;last if $line=~m/^[.]$/;push@l,$line}END{print@l,$/}'`

**OLD ANSWER**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> in Windows? The flag that is already built-in. On Unix you'd use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: That merely stops the process.  It does work I need it to break out of the loop.  I need it to stop taking <STDIN> and then move on to the next function.

Comment: Thanks for the help....now I have to figure out a way to get <STDIN> to work with open().